# Сдвиг центра графика

Tags: python, математика, matplotlib, график, дискретная-математика

При разработке программы отображения графика функции возникла задача скроллинга графика по оси Y вверх или вниз без изменения масштаба.

Т.е. необходимо сдвинуть границы отображаемой части графика так, чтобы масштаб не изменился, но середина отображаемой на экране части графика по оси Y стала равна новому значению Yсрнов.

```
Например, если: Ymin = 0,       Ymax = 10,  Yсрнов = 15, 

то правильный ответ:    Yminнов = 10,   Ymaxнов = 20.
```

Необходимо написать формулу расчета Yminнов и Ymaxнов по известным Ymin, Ymax, Yсрнов.
Входные данные: Ymin, Ymax, Yсрнов.

Comment: во-первых, непонятно, как у вас получилось новое значение. во-вторых - здесь не дают задания, здесь обращаются за помощью, если у вас в вашем коде что-то не получается.

Comment: Yсрнов = Yminнов + Y maxнов / 2. Это задача с интервью поэтому какой-то конкретики нету.

Comment: @Volear, на этом ресурсе помогают тем, кто столкнулся с затруднениями, __пытаясь самостоятельно что-то сделать__. Ваш вопрос сейчас выглядит как задание, которое вы даете нам. Приведите в вопросе собственную попытку решения и укажите с чем именно у вас возникли затруднения.